# Как отправить или принять значения с нескольких форм?

Tags: python, post, flask, get

Как сделать, чтобы уведомление о записи данных запоминалось? Может, надо скрытые параметры передавать?

Сейчас, если записать шаблон файла - сообщение о его записи сохранится, но если записать обложку файла, то останется сообщение о записи обложки, а сообщение о записи шаблона - пропадет.

Как сделать, чтобы это сообщение оставалось?

Обработчик адреса:

```
@MyApp.route('/upload_file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    dict_form = {}
    dict_form_post = request.form.to_dict()
    try:
        dict_form['mes_template'] = dict_form_post['mes_template']
    except:
        dict_form['mes_template'] = 'Запишите шаблон файла'
    try:
        dict_form['mes_cover_template'] = dict_form_post['mes_cover_template']
    except:
        dict_form['mes_cover_template'] = 'Запишите обложку шаблона'


    dict_keys = request.files
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'template_file' in dict_keys:
            if write_post_files(file=dict_keys['template_file'],
                                path_upload='UPLOAD_FOLDER_template'):
                dict_form['mes_template'] = 'Шаблон файла записан'
        if 'cover_file' in dict_keys:
            if write_post_files(file=request.files['cover_file'],
                                path_upload='UPLOAD_FOLDER_cover'):
                dict_form['mes_cover_template'] = 'Обложка шаблона файла записана'

    return render_template("loading_template.html", message=dict_form)
```

Страница с формой:

```
<div class="center">
            <center>

                <h2>{{message['mes_template']}}</h2>
                <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input type=file name=template_file>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input type=submit value=Загрузить>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div class="center">
            <center>
                <h2> {{message['mes_cover_template']}} </h2>
                <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input type=file name=cover_file>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input type=submit value=Загрузить>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </center>
        </div>
```

Дополнение:

Сделал скрытое поле и в него передаю значение, но оно почему-то сохраняет только первое слово из фразы:

```
 <div class="center">
            <center>

                <h2>{{message['mes_template']}}</h2>
                <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input type=file name=template_pptx>
                        <input type="hidden" name="mes_cover_template" value={{message['mes_cover_template']}}>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input type=submit value=Загрузить>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div class="center">
            <center>
                <h2> {{message['mes_cover_template']}} </h2>
                <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input type=file name=cover_file>
                        <input type="hidden" name="mes_template" value={{message['mes_template']}}>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input type=submit value=Загрузить>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </center>
        </div>
```

Comment: очень неправильная обработка формы

Comment: @eri, как сделать правильно?